# Expressing a geometric axiom in logic

Tags: geometry, logic, proof-explanation, predicate-logic

This question is motivated by one of my previous questions, [Basic geometry in logic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092782/basic-geometry-in-logic). For convenience, I'll copy all the required content out in this question.

Let $\mathcal{L}_{\text {inc }}$ be a first order language that consists of only relation symbols $\{P, L, I\}$ where $P$ and $L$ are unary relation symbols and $I$ is a binary relation symbol. An incidence structure $\mathfrak{A}$ is an $\mathcal{L}_{\text {inc }}$ -structure where the elements of $P^{\mathfrak{A}}$ are interpreted as points, elements of $L^{\mathfrak{A}}$ are interpreted as lines and $I^{\mathfrak{A}} \subseteq P^{\mathfrak{A}} \times L^{\mathfrak{A}}$ is the incidents relation. When $(p, l) \in I^{\mathfrak{A}}$ then we say point $p$ is incident with line $l$. Express $\mathrm{~A} 1$ as an $L_{i n c}$-sentence.

(A1) Any two distinct points are incident with exactly one line;

The official solution is given,

$\mathrm{A} 1:\forall v_{1}, v_{2}\left(\left(P\left(v_{1}\right) \wedge P\left(v_{2}\right)\right) \rightarrow\left(\exists v_{3}\left(L\left(v_{3}\right) \wedge I\left(v_{1}, v_{3}\right) \wedge I\left(v_{2}, v_{3}\right) \wedge\left(\left(\forall v_{4}\left(L\left(v_{4}\right) \wedge I\left(v_{1}, v_{4}\right) \wedge I\left(v_{2}, v_{4}\right)\right) \rightarrow\right.\right.\right.\right.\right.$
$\left.\left.\left.v_{3} \doteq v_{4}\right)\right)\right)$.

Now, I was confused about how/why the meaning of 'distinct points' is expressed in the above sentence. When I attempted this exercise again, my solution looked like:

$\mathrm{A} 1:\forall v_{1}, v_{2}, \left(\left(P\left(v_{1}\right) \wedge P\left(v_{2}\right) \land (\lnot (v_1 = v_2))\right) \rightarrow \left(\exists v_{3}\left(L\left(v_{3}\right) \wedge I\left(v_{1}, v_{3}\right) \wedge I\left(v_{2}, v_{3}\right) \wedge\left(\left(\forall v_{4}\left(L\left(v_{4}\right) 
 \land (\lnot (v_4 = v_3)) \rightarrow \lnot(I(v_1,v_4) \land I(v_2,v_4)))\right) \right.\right.\right.\right.\right.$

Here, I thought the $(\lnot (v_1 = v_2))$ was needed to express 'any two *distinct* points'. Why is the official solution correct without this? Also, is my attempted solution correct?

Comment: Correct; you have to use $v_1 \ne v_2$ in order to specify that the two points are two and not one.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Thanks for the comment! Am I correct to think that the official solution is incomplete/incorrect without it?

Comment: You are quite right: the official solution does not capture the condition that the points $v_1$ and $v_2$ are distinct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the official formulation is missing that important aspect of points being distinct. Your formulation expresses that well.